# I don't want any parameter to the binding adapter than how to use that property in xml

Tags: android, kotlin, android-binding-adapter

I have created binding adapter to return editText string to upper case as below.

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["app:holder", "custom:holderAttrChanged"], requireAll = false)
fun setHolder(editText : EditText, text : String?, listener : InverseBindingListener) {
        editText.doOnTextChanged{ _ : CharSequence?, _ : Int, _ : Int, _ : Int ->
                listener.onChange()
        }
}
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "app:holder", event = "custom:holderAttrChanged")
fun getHolder(editText : EditText) : String? {
        return editText.text.toString().toUpperCase()
}
```

and in XML

```
   <EditText
            android:id="@+id/dfsc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:hint="@string/lname"
            android:text="@{viewModel.txtName}"
            app:holder="@={viewModel.txtName}"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text" />
```

Here in Binding adapter I have passed an parameter  `text : String?` so that in xml I can use `app:holder="@={viewModel.txtName}"` but that parameter is useless and without it i can't set `app:holder` in xml ,so how to remove that useless parameter??